# How to use efficient java in memory database to mock Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle11g, h2

I have a lot of DAO tests which access the database.
I tried to mock them using Java in memory database like H2.
But the problem is the ddl scripts contain partition statements which does not seem to be supported by H2.
I basically want to use the same ddl scripts as in production and do not want to modify them in any manner for my "unit" tests.
I also tried HSQL, but found H2 more closely resembles oracle, but even then it doesnt support partition.
Is there a workaround for this ?

I did look at the following
[Create an in-memory database structure from an Oracle instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784843/create-an-in-memory-database-structure-from-an-oracle-instance)
It talks about using H2 but I have already mentioned its shortcomings.
Looking for some alternatives.

Comment: You can't mock an Oracle database (or any DBMS that is) if you want to have meaningful tests. Setup a test-instance against which you run the tests. Btw: you should mention if you are actually speaking about *partitioning* or *window functions* (that use `over(partition by ..`)

Comment: +1 for @a_horse_with_no_name's comment. Each database has a slightly different syntax, you will do well to set up a test instance of oracle

Comment: @MiserableVariable It depends on the complexity of the DAOs and on what you want to test. If the DAOs just do simple CRUD operations, H2 is by far sufficient for *unit* tests. But I agree there should also be tests (i.e. integration tests) running on Oracle.

Comment: Correct, in general it is ok to use H2 if the SQL capabilities used by your program is supported by H2 and Oracle in the same manner, i.e. without any subtle differences. It may also ok if you are using an OR mapping library/framework. But in practice I have found it necessary to use the actual db server to be used in production

Answer (score 2):

If you want meaningful tests, you'll need to run them against an instance of the same database version as you will run in production.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Oracle's data dictionary to generate a H2 schema containing tables, their relationships, indices, constraints, etc. I am using such a generated schema for tests on an in-memory H2 database.

For example to get all tables and their columns, you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
  ut.table_name,
  utc.column_name,
  utc.data_type,
  utc.data_length,
  utc.data_precision
  FROM user_tables ut JOIN user_tab_columns utc
    ON ut.table_name = utc.table_name;
```

Similar queries can be made for foreign keys, other constraints, indices, sequences and all other things you need for your tests. What you further need is a templating engine to transform the results of the queries into an H2 DDL script.

Comment: But that still won't "implement" support for windowing functions or Oracle specific SQL extensions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nope, but at least it solves the problem with Oracle-specific DDLs.